# Finding discontinuity of this function

Tags: calculus

let $$f(x)=x+\frac{\sin x}{2x-\frac{4}{x-1}}$$

So my question is when we organise f(x) in a way such that it becomes :

$$f(x)=\frac{2x^3-2x^2-4x+\sin x(x-1)}{2x^2-2x-4}$$

When we didn't organise f(x) it looked like it was discontinuous at $x=1$
But when we get rid of all the fractions it's not discontinuous at $x=1$

My question is? Do we say that $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$ or $f(x)$ is already continuous at $x=1$

I found out that we say it has a removable discontinuity but I didn't cancel out any terms or anything, I just "organised" $f(x)$ $lim$ already exists at $f(x)$

I couldn't understand why we say it has a removable discontinuity?

Comment: sorry I meant $x=1$

Comment: This is much like the case of functions like $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$, which is undefined (not really discontinuous) at $x=0$, but which can be reduced to a continuous function. Some books call this a "removable discontinuity."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Nothing to do with what I'm asking

Comment: 'f' is not continuous at 'x=1' because 'f' isn't defined at that point.  Rearranging a function like you did changes the domain of the function.  'f' has a removable discontinuity at 'x=1' because the limits from the left and the right are equal so you can define the function piecewisely and get a continuously differentiable function.  In some cases you can just use algebra to cancel terms and get a function that works but this is not always true.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Remember here I didn't use algebra to cancel terms or anything, I just rearranged the function. Does rearranging the function count as removing the discontinuity and re-defining the function?

Comment: Assuming you did the algebra correctly then it's the same function because it's still not continuous at 1 or 2.

Comment: Yes, you did cancel the term $(x-1)$, however implicitly that was. $\frac4{x-1}$ is not defined for $x=1$. Outside the definition gaps at $x=\pm 1$ and $x=2$ the first and your transformed expressions are defined and equal.

Comment: Okay I understood that doing such operations would mean that we re-arrenged the function thus defined a new one.

Comment: @Xenidia Actually, it is exactly what you are asking. Don't be so quick to dismiss.